# Open leaflet marker using url parameter not working now that markercluster is used

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, markerclusterer

I have a leaflet application at http://atlantaartmap.com. The javascript it uses is http://atlantaartmap.com/lazy_art.js.

At line 16, I grab a url parameter that can be used to open the map on a specific piece. While creating the markers, there is a piece of code at line 71 that checks to see if the most recently created marker has the ID referred to in the URL.

This code used to work, but I recently added marker clusters to the website and it no longer does. It still pans and zooms to the marker, but the popup does not open. Here is an example.

http://atlantaartmap.com/index.html?piece=40

```
if (marker.feature.properties.pieceID == pieceID) {
    map.setView(marker.getLatLng(), newZoom());
    marker.openPopup();
}
```

I'm not sure why, but map.setView() works and marker.openPopup() doesn't.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess (am unable to test this) is that your map is still zooming while you call `openPopup` on the marker. At that time the marker isn't added to the map yet because of your cluster so the popup won't show. You could try to wait untill the `setView` method has completed by listening to the `zoomend` event and then open the popup:

```
if (marker.feature.properties.pieceID == pieceID) {
    map.setView(marker.getLatLng(), newZoom()).once('zoomend', function () {
        marker.openPopup();
    });
}
```

If that won't work you can try to use a little delay with `setTimeout`:

```
if (marker.feature.properties.pieceID == pieceID) {
    map.setView(marker.getLatLng(), newZoom()).once('zoomend', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            marker.openPopup();
        }, 500); // Uses millisecs, you might need to fiddle around with it
    });
}
```

Another option could be to wait for the marker's `add` event:

```
if (marker.feature.properties.pieceID == pieceID) {
    marker.once('add', function () {
        marker.openPopup();
    });
    map.setView(marker.getLatLng(), newZoom());
}
```

Hope that helps, as said am unable to test this due to the complexity of your case so i'm not sure. Good luck!

Comment: Ah, thanks. I have little JS experience, and I just assumed that the zoom line would be finished before it attempted to open the popup. I did have a similar feeling, though, as I have had some weird buggy moments on clustered icons. I'll try out some of these solutions later and let you know how things go. Thanks!

Comment: The once('add'.. solution solved the problem, and is also a very neat trick. Thanks! I'm going to see if I can find some other cool uses for it.

Comment: Nice to hear, yeah, there's lots of cool stuff in Leaflet. It never hurts to read through the reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html if you got some spare time. good luck on your project!

Comment: Thanks. I have read through a lot of mapbox tutorials, but I think reading the more detailed leaflet documentation is probably what I need to do to take things to the next level.